# Extracting spatial information from a web map

Tags: geojson, web-mapping, json

I'm trying to extract spatial information from this website:
https://www.ausgrid.com.au/Outages/Current-Outages

Basically, they have a map showing all current outages and I want to get spatial data being shown in the map may it be JSON or GeoJSON or whatever format. Note that this is live data and I would like to extract the points/polygons on specific time intervals. Does anyone know how I can do this?

[image]

Comment: Have you researched if this is a map service (on top of Google data) or whether it's a feature service? The data isn't present in the former, but it might be in the latter. You may need to review the Terms of Service, since, even if technically feasible, web scraping is often a violation of the TOS.

Comment: Using the Network Tab in the browser console is always a good start for stuff like this. Have a look for a call called `GetViewPortInfo`. But as @Vince already said, you might get in trouble scraping data from some website if it is not allowed!

Answer (score 1):

I bit of digging in the browser debugger network section revealed some useful URLs for getting data from the outage site. URLs below are for the planned outages, but I'm sure there are equivalents for the current outages.

You can get JSON list of planned outages with coordinates and `WebId` identifier from the following URL (plain GET): https://www.ausgrid.com.au/webapi/OutageMapData/GetFuturePlannedOutageMarkers. List looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Customers": "85",
    "Coords": [
      {
        "lat": -33.71821,
        "lng": 151.13601
      }
    ],
    "OutageDisplayType": "P",
    "WebId": 62572
  },
  {
    "Customers": "94",
    "Coords": [
      {
        "lat": -33.83988,
        "lng": 151.24174
      }
    ],
    "OutageDisplayType": "P",
    "WebId": 62912
  },
.
.
.
]
```

Detailed JSON info about planned outages is available from the following URL (POST request): https://www.ausgrid.com.au/webapi/OutageListData/GetDetailedPlannedOutages. Info looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Area": "Cronulla",
    "Cause": "Critical electricity network changes for infrastructure projects",
    "Detail": "",
    "Customers": "less than 10",
    "EndDateTime": "2023-08-30T17:00:00",
    "StartDateTime": "2023-08-28T07:00:00",
    "Status": "Cancelled",
    "Streets": "Captain Cook Dr",
    "WebId": 63213,
    "JobId": "NECF81577"
  },
  {
    "Area": "Marrickville, Camperdown, Newtown, Auburn, Arncliffe, Bardwell Valley, Lidcombe, Berala, Regents Park",
    "Cause": "Overhead individual service wire replacement",
    "Detail": "Each property will experience one power outage of approximately 2 hours between the times above.",
    "Customers": "368",
    "EndDateTime": "2023-09-01T17:00:00",
    "StartDateTime": "2023-08-28T07:00:00",
    "Status": "Proceeding as scheduled",
    "Streets": "Addison Rd, Alma Ave, Australia St, Brompton St, Cardigan St, Cumberland Rd, Dowling St, East St, Edinburgh Rd, Enmore Rd, Fitzroy St, Garners Ave, Hall St, Hamilton St, Hastings St, Hawkhurst St, Holmesdale St, James St, Lansdowne St, Lorraine Ave, Northcote St, Northumberland Rd, Park Rd, Parramatta Rd, Percy St, Pile St, Princes Rd, Queen St, Rawson St, Sackville St, Short St, Skarratt St, Sloane St, Smith St, Station Rd, Susan St, Tavistock St, Water St",
    "WebId": 64365,
    "JobId": "NECF84760"
  },
.
.
.
]
```